# nginx not allowing large file uploads with SSL enabled

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, upload

When I set client_max_body_size 0; without ssl, the file upload process is working. However, when I switch to ssl, it is completely ignoring this directive. This is only happening with nginx on, if I use just sails, it works fine via SSL. Debug logs are at the bottom of the post.

My configuration for nginx.conf looks like this:

```
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    #server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    client_max_body_size 0;
```

My configuration for my VHost looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
   server_name mysite.co.uk;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}



server {
listen 443;
ssl on;
server_name mysslsite.co.uk;
    client_max_body_size 0;

ssl_certificate /ssl/mycert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /ssl/mycertkey.key;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains";
server_tokens off;

location / {
    client_body_temp_path /tmp/;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_pass https://localip:port;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Here is the debug logs when it is not working:

```
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 event timer: 18, old: 1484739321930, new: 1484739322088
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 http empty handler
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 http lingering close handler
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 SSL_read: 0
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 SSL_get_error: 5
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 lingering read: 0
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 http request count:1 blk:0
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 http close request
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 http log handler
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE7759C630
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE77598150
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE775C43F0, unused: 4
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE77539DB0, unused: 8
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE775AB400, unused: 2446
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 close http connection: 18
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 SSL_shutdown: 1
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 event timer del: 18: 1484739321930
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 reusable connection: 0
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE775A0A80
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE775D1BE0
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE775AF660, unused: 16
2017/01/18 11:35:17 [debug] 19626#19626: *67 free: 000055FE775E9CC0, unused: 400
```

Any ideas as to what I could be missing would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that this is nginx issue, not backend?

Comment: Definitely nginx, if I switch nginx off and use sails over port 443, works fine. It also works fine if I switch SSL off. It seems that switching SSL on disables the client_max_body_size 0;